# Android default print popup not detecting printer which is connected paired through my app but that is not the same for other apps

Tags: android, reactjs, bluetooth, native, printers

So I made an app https://github.com/needJobCoder/bluetoothAppCodewick

The app pairs and after modifying some code I was able to print and connect . However when trying to print from the link shown below the android phone directs to a default popup which doesn't detect the paired printer. You can use this link to see the popup https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-to-print-rzdhd?codemirror=1

However on using another app like rawbt I was able to not only connect , print but also the printer being detected by the default pop up

Why is this happening is there some library that I can use to setup this or native code?